# Jquery if string matches value in array

Tags: javascript, jquery

The product page on my website displays the `#productID` within a string i.e "Product ID: 743961". Using jQuery I want to take this `#productID` string and compare it to the array of IDs. If the `#productID` matches an ID within the array I want to append a message.

```
<div id="productID"> Product ID: 743961 </div>
```

I was initially trying to do the following, but was struggling to get the desired results.

```
var myArray = [ 743961, 743963, 743965 ];
$( "#prod_code:contains('myArray')" ).css( "text-decoration", "underline" );
```

My array has over 2,000 items, so this may not be the best solution. I am aware that Ajax would be the best solution, but am unable to use it in this instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With such a large array it sounds like AJAX would be a better solution. However, if you must use this pattern, you would first need to grab the productId value from the text of the element and then you can determine if it exists in the array. Something like this:

```
var productId = $.trim($('#productID').text().split(':')[1]);
if ($.inArray(productId, myArray) >= 0)
    $('#prod_code').css('text-decoration', 'underline');
```

This is obviously a rather simple example, you would most likely need more validation on the extraction of the productId to make it more robust.

Comment: I like this better than my solution, +1. Running thousands of selector matches will be expensive.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Rory. I know Ajax would be the best solution for this example, but I am unable to use it in this instance as I have limited access to the FTP.

Comment: You need to fix the ID as well as your if statement. $.inArray returns -1 if not found, but the index otherwise. So in your example if the array matched the first element, you'd get 0 returned and false, when you want true. Also, trim returns a string. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nn9swwra/

Comment: Thanks for raising those issues @j08691, I've updated the answer.